# FlatList equivalent to ListView's adjacentRowHighlighted in renderSeparator

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-listview

When using `ListView`'s `renderSeparator` function you get the `adjacentRowHighlighted` parameter so it's possible to style the separator differently depending on whether one of its neighbouring rows is being highlighted by the user.

I can't find the same functionality for `FlatList` and its `ItemSeparatorComponent`.

Is this possible to do with `FlatList`?